# How do I remove the before and after arrow only from one <th></th> table?

Tags: jquery, datatable, jquery-plugins, bootstrap-5, pseudo-class

I'am trying **to remove** the pseudo Css class (before and after) from this first `<th>#</th>`
tag, from a table (**[bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/)** and **[responsive Datable plugin](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/no-classes.html)**)... is there a way to remove this using I don't know... **javaScript --> Jquery?**

**This image will make this clear...
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlfxt.png)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question needs some more explanation.

For example, if you are using the JS plugin developed by DataTables.net, the sort tokens are a background image. In this case, it is sufficient to add a style element at the end of the page to destroy them.

```
<style>
   .sorting,
   table.dataTable thead .sorting_asc,
   table.dataTable thead .sorting_desc {
      background-image:unset  !important;
   }
</style>
```